# How to place an background image in crystal Report Document

Tags: c#, windows, dataset, report

Today I had an issue in align a Invoice in Crystal report.Becuase it coulnt fit on the invoice printing space. Then I thought if Scan that printing space as an image then insert to crystal report document to organize the fields, but that image visible only in on section eg: report header, page header etc.. could you please tell me how to fit the image into the whole document.?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such think like background for CR page. But you can try do some trick. Add image to Page Header, suppress rest sections. Add subreport to Page Header, by importing Invoice rpt. Now you can edit subreport to fit image on preview, and then save it as rpt.